# Using input from extra variable to retrieve a value from a host variable fails?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am trying to retrieve information about a variable for a particular group using extra variables on input. It seems to be working if I hard-code the name of the group but when I use a variable like *"{{  deployment }}"* which would refer to *cluster_2* it will fail.

My setup:

I have a host file that looks something like this:

```ini
[cluster_1]
1_node1 ansible_host=192.168.1.1  
1_node2 ansible_host=192.168.1.2  
1_node3 ansible_host=192.168.1.3  

[cluster_1:vars]
node1_ip=192.168.1.1
node2_ip=192.168.1.2
node3_ip=192.168.1.3
port=9202

[cluster_2]
2_node1 ansible_host=192.168.1.4 
2_node2 ansible_host=192.168.1.5  
2_node3 ansible_host=192.168.1.6  

[cluster_2:vars]
node1_ip=192.168.1.4
node2_ip=192.168.1.5
node3_ip=192.168.1.6
port=9202
```

The playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: cluster_1
  #gather_facts: "no"
  tasks:

    - name: Set remote hosts for reindex 
      debug:
        
        #this works
        msg: "hello from {{ansible_hostname  }} ['cluster_2']:['node1_ip'] {{  hostvars[groups['cluster_2'][0]].node1_ip }}"
        
        #this does NOT work
        msg: "hello from {{ansible_hostname  }} ['cluster_2']:['node1_ip'] {{  hostvars[groups['{{ deployment }}'][0]].node1_ip }}" 
pedro@ansible:~/ansible_elasticsearch $
```

The command I run:

```bash
shell> ansible-playbook test1.yml -i /home/pedro/ansible_hosts/test_hosts  --e "deployment=cluster_2" --limit 'cluster_1'
```

I get an error like this:

> fatal: [1_node1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute '{{ deployment }}'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/pedro/ansible_elasticsearch/update_reindex_remote_xtra.yml': line 6, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: Set remote hosts for reindex\n      ^ here\n"}

I looked at  [Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts)  and tried a variation of

```
{% if 'cluster_2' in group_names %}
   # some part of a configuration file that only applies to webservers
{% endif %}
```

Which did not work.

Run

```
var: "hostvars"
```

to try to see how this structure works but I could not figure out what I am doing wrong, I found this: (amongst lots of other data)

```yaml
"deployment": "cluster_2",
            "group_names": [
                "cluster_2"
            ],
```

I really think there needs to be a way to do it, hard coding is against why we would want to use automation.

Comment: this is what is expected:```ok: [1_node1] => {
    "msg": "hello from es_1_node1 [cluster_2']:['node1_ip'] 192.168.1.4"

Comment: (a) please do not put code in comments, instead [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74418074/edit) (b) it's a very, very, very, very common mistake that mustaches do not stack and you have single-quoted them anyway, causing the error you reported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The playbook below shows how to get what you want

```yaml
- hosts: cluster_1
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_host }} {{ hostvars[groups.cluster_2.0].node1_ip }}"
        
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_host }} {{ hostvars[groups[deployment].0].node1_ip }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook test1.yml  -e "deployment=cluster_2"

PLAY [cluster_1] *****************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [1_node1] => 
  msg: 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.4
ok: [1_node2] => 
  msg: 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.4
ok: [1_node3] => 
  msg: 192.168.1.3 192.168.1.4

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [1_node1] => 
  msg: 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.4
ok: [1_node2] => 
  msg: 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.4
ok: [1_node3] => 
  msg: 192.168.1.3 192.168.1.4

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
1_node1: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
1_node2: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
1_node3: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

**Dot vs. bracket notation**

See [Referencing key:value dictionary variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#referencing-key-value-dictionary-variables). The expressions below are equivalent

```yaml
{{ hostvars[groups.cluster_2.0].node1_ip }}
```

```yaml
{{ hostvars[groups['cluster_2'].0].node1_ip }}
```

Comment: can you please decribe the difference between ``` ['cluster_2']:['node1_ip'] {{  hostvars[groups['cluster_2'][0]].node1_ip }} and your version ``` {{ hostvars[groups.cluster_2.0].node1_ip }}"```` Similarly why this works: ``` {{ hostvars[groups[deployment].0].node1_ip }}" ``` and mine does not? ```  {{  hostvars[groups['{{ deployment }}'][0]].node1_ip }}"  ``` What is the magic logic here and where can I learn more? Appreciate.  Ďakujem.

Comment: You have to understand [mre] first. What purpose is ` ['cluster_2']:['node1_ip']` in your question?

Comment: the idea to point to a particular deployment is to retrieve information about its nodes, like IP, or FQDN and port and pass it to further configuration mechanism. I am a novice in a learning phase, the documentation was not sufficient for me to fully understand how this works unfortunately.  I honestly do not understand the difference between how I followed the documentation, which works when hard-coded, That solution is using brackets (?arrays?) vs your elegant solutions with dots. Will appreciate any knowledge you can share

Comment: I added the link to dot vs. bracket notation. Delete the redundant comments, please. You've already been told so by mdaniel. Your question will be closed if you don't comply. See [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work).

Comment: @vladimir-bodka I just noticed the link: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-at-runtime  Thank you.